# The default DbConfiguration instance was used before the 'EntityFrameworkConfiguration' type was discovered

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
 public class EntityFrameworkConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public EntityFrameworkConfiguration()
        {
            this.SetModelCacheKey(ctx => new EntityModelCacheKey((ctx.GetType().FullName + ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString).GetHashCode()));
        }
    }
```

To make the above code work i have added below line in web.config

But for other project where i am using the assembly reference i am getting exception:

> {"The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity
>   Framework before the 'EntityFrameworkConfiguration' type was
>   discovered. An instance of 'EntityFrameworkConfiguration' must be set
>   at application start before using any Entity Framework features or
>   must be registered in the application's config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information."}

Answer (score 6):

Your question doesn't state how you are using this custom DbConfiguration.

You could get this error a couple of different ways.

**Configuration style setup**

as described here: [Entity Framework Config File Settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx)

**Configuration as code**

as described here: [Entity Framework Code-Based Configuration (EF6 onwards)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj680699(v=vs.113).aspx)
You can `hack` at this style by doing things like DbConfiguration.SetConfiguration(xxxx).  I didnt find this useful at all.

What this really comes down to is how you construct your DbContext.

**Configuration file style constructors**
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs#L75
With no arguments - EF6 is uses the configuraiton files to determine the right DbCofniguration to use

with some "connection string-like" arguments again EF6 is using configuration files to determine the DbConfiguration

no config, or bad config - and you will get this sort or exception

**Configuration as Code style constructors**
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/DbContext.cs#L139

I think this yields better control.

Attribute your DbContext, then use a manually created DbConnection

```
public class EntityFrameworkConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public EntityFrameworkConfiguration()
    {
        this.SetModelCacheKey(ctx => new EntityModelCacheKey((ctx.GetType().FullName + ctx.Database.Connection.ConnectionString).GetHashCode()));
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(EntityFrameworkConfiguration))]
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection) 
        : base(existingConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
    { }


    public DbSet<Stuff> Stuff { get; set; }
}


using(var conn = new SqlConnection(asqlserverConnectionString))
            using (var db = new MyContext(conn, true))
            {
                var value = await db.Stuff.Where(s => s.xxx.Equals(primaryKey)).Select(s => new { s.BinaryContent } ).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [Code-based configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based), try updating the config file thusly:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MyNamespace.MyDbConfiguration, MyAssembly">
    ...Your EF config...
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: more info can be found here: https://blog.jonschneider.com/2015/12/fix-default-dbconfiguration-instance.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have two different edmx files and both are in different class libraries.
I got this error when i added those two libraries in the same project.

I don't have any single clue how is that sorted out but; when i call any method from my first DbContext class, the second one worked like miracle happened. It was throwing this error when second context class called first.
My Ef version is: 6.4

Comment: I recently encountered this during some refactoring. There was a hand-written partial class definition that grafted the DbConfigurationType attribute onto the context generated by one edmx but not the other. The context with the attribute had always been instantiated first prior to the refactor, but was instantiated second after the refactor. Giving every partial class for a generated context (and switching to the Type overload rather than the String overload of the attribute) fixed the issue. This was with 6.3.0.