# Error: default DbConfiguration instance was used by Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a DAL project with this ApplicationContext.cs

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyConfiguration))]
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
  public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }

...
}
```

but when I instance it in an other project

```
using (var databaseContext = new ApplicationDbContext())
{ }
```

I get this error:

> The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework
>   before the 'MyConfiguration' type was discovered. An instance of
>   'MyConfiguration' must be set at application start before using any
>   Entity Framework features or must be registered in the application's
>   config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for
>   more information.

I tried to solve it updating the web.config file, inserting codeConfigurationType in  node, but I get the same error.

Can anyone help me?

### UPDATE

My custom class is this:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The default DbConfiguration instance was used before the 'EntityFrameworkConfiguration' type was discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177785/the-default-dbconfiguration-instance-was-used-before-the-entityframeworkconfigu)

Comment: Can you please share the Configuration class code

Comment: @WaelAbbas

    public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public MyConfiguration()
        {
            SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(2, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
        }
    }

Comment: Please update the question with it

Comment: @WaelAbbas done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

After reading this article **Moving DbConfiguration**:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699

I solved changing my Context class as below:

```
[DbConfigurationType("DAL.Context.MyConfiguration, DAL")] 
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the error you should create an instance of `ApplicationDbContext` class on application start on `Startup` class

Startup class

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
```

ApplicationDbContext class

```
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        this.Database.Create();
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
```

Also if you can share the full example it will be better.