# An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DocumentController'

Tags: c#, constructor, dependencies, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have created a project to download multiple documents in my solution. 
And It is working very fine on my local IIS, but I am stuck in a strange situation that I have published this application to the production server and now it is giving me below error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DocumentController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
>           System.InvalidOperationException
>            at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerActivatorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.b__0() at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerActivatorTracer.System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType) at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerDescriptorTracer.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<CreateController>b__0() at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.TraceBeginEnd(ITraceWriter traceWriter, HttpRequestMessage request, String category, TraceLevel level, String operatorName, String operationName, Action`1 beginTrace, Action execute, Action`1 endTrace, Action`1 errorTrace) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.Tracers.HttpControllerDescriptorTracer.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at InEight.Platform.Services.Handler.IEEE754CompatibleHandler.d__0.MoveNext() in F:\vsts4_work\12\s\Platform\PlatformFramework\InEight.Platform\Web\Handler\IEEE754CompatibleHandler.cs:line 20 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.d__17`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.Tracing.ITraceWriterExtensions.<TraceBeginEndAsyncCore>d__17`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__24.MoveNext()
>           
>           An error has occurred.
>           An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DocumentController (ReflectionActivator), Services = [InEight.Core.Web.Services.Controllers.WebApi.DocumentController], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DocumentsService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [InEight.Platform.Services.Data.IDocumentsService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DocumentsService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [InEight.Platform.Services.IDocumentsService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = CoreDataContext (ReflectionActivator), Services = [System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter, InEight.Platform.Site.Services.Contexts.ICoreDataContext, InEight.Platform.DataAccess.Contexts.IDbContext], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(InEight.Platform.TenantInfo)' on type 'CoreDataContext'. ---> The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework before the 'AuthDataContextConfiguration' type was discovered. An instance of 'AuthDataContextConfiguration' must be set at application start before using any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)
>           Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException
>            at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType) in C:\projects\autofac-webapi\src\Autofac.Integration.WebApi\AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.cs:line 76 at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)</StackTrace>
>           <InnerException>
>           <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
>           <ExceptionMessage>An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DocumentsService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [InEight.Platform.Services.Data.IDocumentsService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = DocumentsService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [InEight.Platform.Services.IDocumentsService], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.MatchingScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = CoreDataContext (ReflectionActivator), Services = [System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter, InEight.Platform.Site.Services.Contexts.ICoreDataContext, InEight.Platform.DataAccess.Contexts.IDbContext], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = None, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(InEight.Platform.TenantInfo)' on type 'CoreDataContext'. ---> The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework before the 'AuthDataContextConfiguration' type was discovered. An instance of 'AuthDataContextConfiguration' must be set at application start before using any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information. (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.)</ExceptionMessage>
>           <ExceptionType>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</ExceptionType>
>           <StackTrace> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.b__5_0() at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.AutowiringParameter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<CanSupplyValue>b__0() at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate() at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)

Web Api Controller,

```
public class DocumentController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly Lazy<ICoreDataContext> _CoreDataContext;
    private readonly IDocumentsService _documentsService;
    protected ICoreDataContext CoreDataContext { get { return _CoreDataContext.Value; } }

    public DocumentController(IContextFactory contextFactory, IDocumentsService documentsService, IAppLog appLog) : base(appLog, contextFactory.Tenant)
    {
        _CoreDataContext = new Lazy<ICoreDataContext>(contextFactory.GetCoreContext);
        _documentsService = documentsService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("MultiDocuments")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadMultiDocument(string documentIds)
    {
        try
        {
            var user = GetAuthenticatedUser();

            return await _documentsService.DownloadMultiDocumentAsync(user, documentIds);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw HttpError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And from the following DocumentsService class, I am calling the newly created project's DocumentService class like following,

```
  public class DocumentsService : CoreDataService, IDocumentsService
{
    private readonly IProjectsService _projectsService;
    private Dictionary<long, bool> projectAvailibility;
    private Dictionary<long, bool> projectDocumentTypeIdValidity;
    private readonly Services.IDocumentsService _documentService;

    public DocumentsService(IProjectsService projectsService, IContextFactory contextFactory, IAppLog appLog, IPermissionService permissionService,Services.IDocumentsService documentService): base(contextFactory, appLog, permissionService)
    {
        _projectsService = projectsService;
        _documentService = documentService;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadMultiDocumentAsync(IClaimedUser user, string documentIds)
    {
        return await _documentService.DownloadMultiDocumentAsync(user, documentIds);
    }
}
```

And my new project's service class,

```
public class DocumentService : IDocumentsService
{
    private readonly TenantInfo tenantInfo;
    private readonly ICoreDataContext coreDataContext;
    private readonly IPermissionService permissionService;

    public DocumentService(TenantInfo tenant, ICoreDataContext coreDataContext, IAppLog log, IPermissionService permissionService)
    {
        tenantInfo = tenant;
        this.coreDataContext = coreDataContext;
        this.coreDataContext.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
       this.permissionService = permissionService;
    }

    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DownloadMultiDocumentAsync(IClaimedUser user, string documentId)
    {
       ...
       return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have multiple `DocumentsService` classes? The first one take an instance of `IDocumentsService` too, so that's already self-referential.

Comment: Buried in the exception: *The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework before the 'AuthDataContextConfiguration' type was discovered. An instance of 'AuthDataContextConfiguration' must be set at application start before using any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the application's config file.* Maybe that helps.

Comment: Hmm... this exception is hard to read.... nevertheless, your system requests a parameterless constructor in your controller. This suggest you are using an IoC framework, like unity or autofac. Can you show the code where you are are binding the dependency resolver?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The default DbConfiguration instance was used before the 'EntityFrameworkConfiguration' type was discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177785/the-default-dbconfiguration-instance-was-used-before-the-entityframeworkconfigu)

Comment: @DavidG Yes, I Have multiple class files named "DocumentsService". So changing the class name  will be the solution ?

Comment: @Stefan , I am not able to edit/ update my question so i will post in comment here. (In Startup.cs)                                    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
                        var container = builder.Build();
   GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);builder.RegisterType<Platform.Services.DocumentService>().As<Platform.Services.IDocumentsService>().InstancePerRequest();

Comment: The inner exception suggests that @mjwills 's duplicate is valid. Have you tried that? See:  `An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(InEight.Platform.TenantInfo)' on type 'CoreDataContext'. ---> The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework before the 'AuthDataContextConfiguration' type was discovered. An instance of 'AuthDataContextConfiguration' must be set at application start before using any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the application's config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made a mistake that we missed to include the new project reference  in the Web Api Controller Project.

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\..\Platform\ABC.PlatformFramework\Platform.Services\Platform.Services.csproj">
 <Project>{f439869c-9778-4f88-b0a3-41086b8fdf9c}</Project>
 <Name>ABC.Platform.Services</Name>
</ProjectReference>
```