# Using EF6 SQLite with a plugin

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, system.data.sqlite

I'm implementing an SQLite Database for a plugin using EF6.
However, one of my users gets the error "The default DbConfiguration instance was used before the 'SQLiteConfiguration' type was discovered"

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32177785/the-default-dbconfiguration-instance-was-used-before-the-entityframeworkconfigu), I attributed my context with the SQLiteConfiguration as shown below, but that did not help.
I know that this particular user is also using other plugins for his main software and I highly suspect that this has something to do with it. The EF6 docs specifically mention the case of a plugin database [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/code-based#overriding-dbconfiguration), but I have no idea 1) whether I should implement `MyProviderServices` and `MyConnectionFactory` myself or whether the `System.Data.SQLite` library provides those and 2) how that would change my `SQLiteConfiguration` constructor, i.e. whether to keep the `SetProviderFactory` and `SetProviderServices` lines in there.

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(SQLiteConfiguration))]
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context() : base(
        new SQLiteConnection { ConnectionString = "some_connection_string"}, true)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Foo> Foos{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var sqliteConnectionInitializer = new SqliteDropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges<Context>(modelBuilder);
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(sqliteConnectionInitializer);
    }


public class SQLiteConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public SQLiteConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite", SQLiteFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderFactory("System.Data.SQLite.EF6", SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance);
        SetProviderServices("System.Data.SQLite",
            (DbProviderServices)SQLiteProviderFactory.Instance.GetService(typeof(DbProviderServices)));
    }
}
```

Here is my app.config in case it helps. It was entirely autogenerated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework"
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
                 requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.1" newVersion="4.0.1.1"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                                  culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.4.1" newVersion="4.0.4.1"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Data.SQLite"
                                  culture="neutral"
                                  publicKeyToken="db937bc2d44ff139"
                />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.117.0" newVersion="1.0.117.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider (Entity Framework 6)" invariant="System.Data.SQLite.EF6"
                 description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite (Entity Framework 6)"
                 type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderFactory, System.Data.SQLite.EF6"/>
            <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
            <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite"
                 description=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite"
                 type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!